# ASP.NET web pages unresponsive during File Upload

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, session-timeout

I have an ASP.NET web page with a FileUpload control

```
      <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUploadTN" style="width:250px" runat="server" />
```

One problem is that when uploading big files my asp.net session times out.  This is due to limitation with DiscountAsp.net and non-overridable 20 minute session timeout (unless switch to SqlServer).  No problem uploading the large file, just session then dies shortly after complete.

So, I have a workaround of having a javascript timer periodically access another web page to keep the session alive longer.

```
       function timerEvent()
       {
         jQuery.get( "/svc.aspx?act=ping", function(data) { });
       }
```

This works great, except during file uploads. During the file upload there is no response on the HTTP GET, nor does the request even make it to the svc.aspx page.  I can watch in Fiddler and the GET occurs, but there is no response.  As soon as the file upload is complete, then the responses start up again.   But, if long file upload, my session may be timed out then.

Even if I open a new window in the browser and go to the svc.aspx page directly, it gets stuck in request.  I can open a window in a different app browser (e.g. FF -> Chrome ) window and the svc.aspx responds. So, seems to be issue when in the same session that other HTTP GETs fail to respond during a file upload.

Comment: Try changing it to an `ashx`.

Comment: I will try this, but by itself it doesn't seem like it will keep the session alive.  In some research, looks like I will need to implement IRequiresSessionState also in the IHttpHandler.   Will update later on the progress

Comment: Slaks, I tried the ASHX and it partially worked.  If just the IHttpHandler then I was able to access it during a file upload.  But, once I added the IRequiresSessionState in order to update the Session, then it had the access problem.   Since the main purpose it to update the Session, then it does not seem like this will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For larger files it is better to use some Flash uploader - for example [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) or [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org/)
I prefer to use Uploadify. Below is example from my project.
You have to include uploadify.css and jquery, swfobject and jquery.uploadify JavaScript files and initialize uploadify in you ASPX page:

```
<link href="uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   // <![CDATA[
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#fileInput').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'Scripts/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'Upload.ashx',
            'scriptData': {},
            'cancelImg': 'Images/cancel.png',
            'auto': true,
            'multi': true,
            'fileDesc': 'PDF files',
            'fileExt': '*.pdf',
            'queueSizeLimit': 90,
            'sizeLimit': 4000000,
            'buttonText': 'Browse',
            'folder': '/uploads',
            'onComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
                var message = '<div>' + response + '</div>';
                var results = $('#uploadResults');
                results.html(message + results.html());
            },
            'onAllComplete': function (event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
            }
        });
    });

 // ]]></script>
```

Instead of asp:FileUpload control use input with type - file. Here is needed HTML:

```
    <input id="fileInput" name="fileInput" type="file" />
    <div id="uploadResults"></div>
```

Then create ASHX handler which will process you uploads:

```
public class Upload : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try 
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

        // Validate file for content length, extension etc. 
        // Store file on server or do what you want with file
        // Use context.Response.Write to send messages which will be displayed in <div id="uploadResults"></div> 

        } 
        catch (Exception ex) 
        {
          context.Response.Write("Failed to upload file");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I realized that the ASP.NET File Uploader is not good for large files.  I was considering http://ajaxuploader.com, but I will take a look at this also.  We are already using Flash, so your suggestion should be fine.  The AjaxUploader is already fully ASP.NET, so may be a little easier to integrate regarding being notified when complete, etc., but appears that Uploadify has an event, therefore, should be able to notify my UpdatePanel also.